# Setting samesite in context.xml questions

Tags: tomcat

We have a problem with Chrome and Edge not rendering our Java/JSP website correctly when it's run in an iframe.  Firefox and IE work correctly.

Our research shows that's because the JSESSIONID cookie needs the SameSite attribute set to NONE.

We were able to get the SameSite attribute on our JSESSIONID cookie set to NONE in our localhost environment by make the following change to our context.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Context>
        <CookieProcessor sameSiteCookies="none"/>
</Context>
```

However, when we try to test in our test environment it still doesn't work.  The  SameSite attribute on our JSESSIONID cookie isn't set to NONE.

On our test environment we have the following context.xml files:

```
/opt/apache-tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.30/conf/context.xml
/opt/apache-tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.30/instances/appA/conf/context.xml
/opt/apache-tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.31/conf/context.xml
/opt/apache-tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.31/instances/AppB/conf/context.xml
/opt/apache-tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.21/conf/context.xml
/opt/apache-tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.21/instances/AppC/conf/context.xml
/opt/apache-tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.21/instances/OurApplication/conf/context.xml <== Has samesitecookie="none"
/opt/apache-tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.21/instances/OurApplication/webapps/OurApplication/META-INF/context.xml <== Has samesitecookie="none"
```

We have the **sameSiteCookies="none"** in the 2 above context.xml files.  I'm wondering if it's reading the CookieProcessor from another one.  Is there a way to see which instance of the context.xml you're working with in Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the `same-site` cookie attribute to `None` was [introduced](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=63865#c2) in Tomcat [9.0.28](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/changelog.html#Tomcat_9.0.28_(markt)), but you are using 9.0.21 which does not support `None`. It was back-ported in Tomcat [8.5.48](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/changelog.html#Tomcat_8.5.48_(markt)), but you are using 8.5.31, which also does not support it.

Therefore you have to update your tomcat versions.